# xpath expression to satisfies multiple criteria

Tags: xpath

What should be the xpath expression that returns the *us* entity that satisfies all the following criteria : 
 . The *lo* is « name1 »
. The *na* is « Name1 »

```
<rac>
<us>
    <lo> name1 </lo>
    <na> Name1 </na>
    <pro>
        <val> admin </val>
        <id> 6 </id>
        <des> adminUser </des>
    </pro>
    <pro>
        <val> operator </val>
        <id> 3 </id>
        <des> Operator </des>
    </pro>
</us>

<us>
    <lo> name2 </lo>
    <na> Name2 </na>
    <pro>
        <val> admin </val>
        <id> 1 </id>
        <des> adminU </des>
    </pro>
    <pro>
        <val> power </val>
        <id> 9 </id>
        <des> powerU </des>
    </pro>
</us>
```

Many thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, exactly like you say it (assuming you want `us`):

```
//us[
       lo[normalize-space() = 'name1'] 
   and na[normalize-space() = 'Name1'] 
   and count(pro/val)=2 
   and pro/val[normalize-space() = 'admin'] 
   and pro/val[normalize-space() = 'operator'] ]
```